# uuidgen and $RANDOM doesn't change in find -exec argument

Tags: bash, shell, random, find, command-substitution

I want to get all the instances of a file in my macosx file system and copy them in a single folder of an external hard disk.
I wrote a simple line of code in terminal but when I execute it, there is only a file in the target folder that is replaced at every occurrence it finds.
It seems that the $RANDOM or $(uuidgen) used in a single command return only one value used for every occurrence {} of the find command.
Is there a way to get a new value for every result of the find command?
Thank you.

```
find . -iname test.txt -exec cp {} /Volumes/EXT/$(uuidgen) \;
```

or

```
find . -iname test.txt -exec cp {} /Volumes/EXT/$RANDOM \;
```

Comment: Try `-exec bash -c 'cp {} /Volumes/somewhere/$(uuidgen)'`

Comment: Thank you, it works. If you post it as an aswer I can set it as the solution for my problem.

Comment: `... -exec bash -c 'cp {} /Volumes/somewhere/$(uuidgen)' ...` fails for paths that contain spaces, or various other characters.  The arguments to `cp` need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" /Volumes/somewhere/$(uuidgen)' _ {} \;
```

Thanks to dan and pjh for corrections in comments.

Comment: should be: `find ... -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" /Volumes/somewhere/$(uuidgen)' _ {} \;`

Comment: LGTM.  Upvoted.  I'm paranoid and would quote the second argument to `cp` to allow for weird values of `IFS`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname test.txt -exec bash -c '
    for i do
        cp "$i" "/Volumes/EXT/$RANDOM"
    done' _ {} +
```

You can use `-exec` with `+`, to pass multiple files to a bash loop. You can't use command subs (or multiple commands at all) in a single `-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Bash 4.0 or later, another option is:

```
shopt -s dotglob
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -s nullglob

for testfile in **/test.txt; do
    cp -- "$testfile" "/Volumes/EXT/$(uuidgen)"
done
```

- `shopt -s dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.` (e.g. `.dir/test.txt`)
- `shopt -s globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees
- `shopt -s nocaseglob` causes globs to match in a case-insensitive fashion (like `find` option `-iname` versus `-name`)
- `shopt -s nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs)
- The `--` in `cp -- ...` prevents paths that begin with hyphens (e.g. `-dir/test.txt`) being (mis)treated as options to `cp'
- Note that **this code might fail on versions of Bash prior to 4.3** because symlinks are (stupidly) followed while expanding `**` patterns